# IOS : Ibaction from tableviewcell button to Viewcontroller possible?

Tags: ios, swift

The above action outlet works fine. But is this a standard solution to pass an action from cell to view controller ???

Comment: You should create a separate subclass for your cell, connect the iboutlets and ibactions in that class and then define a protocol to send button action from cell subclass to the viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Say for e.g.,

You have `UIButton` added to the `UITableViewCell` subclass.

In `cellForRowAt` delegate method, once you have that particular `cell` created;
do something like following:

`cell.btnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)`

Here, `btnAdd` is `UIButton` instance variable of `UITableViewCell` subclass.

And `func addTapped(_ sender: Any) {...}` is the method that is being attached to that button.

Comment: Not sure about downvote, but this is something which was a common practice in the past and what OP has asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by: Create outlet of button in cell subclass. And in **cellForRowAt:** addTarget to button and give the action in target.